# Shopify Dawn Theme - Liquid Question - Blank Spaces are showing up in my collections section where conditions have not been met

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

**Concept:** I have built a custom section on the home page that should only show the first variant of products within a collection. NOTE: Gift with purchase is offered with specific variant sizes only, and size varies from product to product.

**Attempted Solution:** Use "variant.weight" as a selector and only show items where the variant has inventory available and is the correct weight. NOTE: This store will not ship via Shopify & does not need to use weight for shipping purposes.

**Issue/Problem:** There are blank spots where items in the collection do not qualify either because the variant does not meet the weight requirement or there is no available inventory.

**Ask**:

1. How can I fix this code so that the blank spaces go away? I assume I need to add {% else %} code, but I have no idea what to add to that line. I tried {% continue %} and that did not accomplish what I was looking to accomplish.
2. Can I show out-of-stock items as "Sold Out" rather than have them
   removed? (I realize I wrote the code to remove items with no
   inventory, I iterate through my code as I am still learning)
3. Is there a more elegant fix/solution that I missed?

Site: https://test-store-colleen.myshopify.com/
Password: thanksforyourhelp

[Snap of collection on the home page with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj6ch.png)

This is the snippet code:

```html
{% comment %}
    Renders a product card

    Accepts:
    - product_card_product: {Object} Product Liquid object (optional)
    - media_size: {String} Size of the product image card. Values are "square" and "portrait". Default is "square" (optional)
    - show_secondary_image: {Boolean} Show the secondary image on hover. Default: false (optional)
    - add_image_padding: {Boolean} Enables padding on the image to space out the grid
    - show_vendor: {Boolean} Show the product vendor. Default: false
    - show_image_outline: {Boolean} Show card outline. Default: true (optional)
    - show_rating: {Boolean} Show the product rating. Default: false

    Usage:
    {% render 'product-card-gwp', show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
{% endcomment %}

{{ 'component-rating.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

    {%- for variant in product_card_product.variants -%}
    {% assign theweight = variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit %}
    {%- if theweight == '9 g' and variant.inventory_quantity != 0 -%}    



<div class="card-wrapper">

  {% capture the_snippet_fave_icon %}{% render 'ssw-widget-faveicon' with product.id %}{% endcapture %}
  {% unless the_snippet_fave_icon contains 'Liquid error' %}
  {{ the_snippet_fave_icon }}
  {% endunless %}
  
  <div class="card-information">
    <div class="card-information__wrapper">
      {%- if show_vendor -%}
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.vendor' | t }}</span>
        <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light">{{ product_card_product.vendor }}</div>
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if product_card_product.featured_media -%}
        <h3 class="card-information__text h5">
          <a href="{{ product_card_product.url | default: '#' }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
            {{ product_card_product.title | escape }}
          </a>
        </h3>
      {%- endif -%}
      
      {% capture the_snippet_review_avg %}{% render 'ssw-widget-avg-rate-listing', product: product %}{% endcapture %}
      {% unless the_snippet_review_avg contains 'Liquid error' %}
      {{ the_snippet_review_avg }}
      {% endunless %}

      {% comment %} TODO: metafield 
      <span class="caption-large light">{{ block.settings.description | escape }}</span>
      {%- if show_rating and product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value != blank -%}
        {% liquid
          assign rating_decimal = 0 
          assign decimal = product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value.rating | modulo: 1 
          if decimal >= 0.3 and decimal <= 0.7
            assign rating_decimal = 0.5
          elsif decimal > 0.7
            assign rating_decimal = 1
          endif 
        %}
        <div class="rating" role="img" aria-label="{{ 'accessibility.star_reviews_info' | t: rating_value: product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value, rating_max: product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value.scale_max }}">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="rating-star color-icon-{{ settings.accent_icons }}" style="--rating: {{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value.rating | floor }}; --rating-max: {{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value.scale_max }}; --rating-decimal: {{ rating_decimal }};"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="rating-text caption">
          <span aria-hidden="true">{{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value }} / {{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating.value.scale_max }}</span>
        </p>
        <p class="rating-count caption">
          <span aria-hidden="true">({{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating_count }})</span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ product_card_product.metafields.reviews.rating_count }} {{ "accessibility.total_reviews" | t }}</span>
        </p>
      {%- endif -%}
      {% endcomment %}
 
{% comment %}      
     Original code NOTE: Also added line for "Free Shipping" below
     {% render 'price', product: product_card_product, price_class: '' %}
      
     Colleen modified code below to show the first variant price under the product on the collection gwp page     
      
{% endcomment %}
      
      {% render 'price', product: product_card_product, use_variant: product_card_product.first_available_variant.id, price_class: price--large -%} 
           <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light"> FREE SHIPPING </div>
      <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light">   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="card card--product{% if product_card_product.featured_media == nil %} card--text-only card--soft{% endif %}{% if product_card_product.featured_media != nil and show_image_outline %} card--outline{% endif %}" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="card__inner">
      {%- if product_card_product.featured_media -%}
        {%- liquid
          assign featured_media_aspect_ratio = product_card_product.featured_media.aspect_ratio

          if product_card_product.featured_media.aspect_ratio == nil
            assign featured_media_aspect_ratio = 1
          endif
        -%}

        <div{% if add_image_padding %} class="card__media-full-spacer"{% endif %}>
          <div class="media media--transparent media--{{ media_size }} media--hover-effect"
            {% if media_size == 'adapt' and product_card_product.featured_media %} style="padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: featured_media_aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;"{% endif %}
          >
            <img
              srcset="{%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 165 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '165x' }} 165w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 360 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '360x' }} 360w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 533 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '533x' }} 533w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 720 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '720x' }} 720w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 940 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '940x' }} 940w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 1066 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '1066x' }} 1066w,{%- endif -%}
                {{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: 'master' }} {{ product_card_product.featured_media.width }}w"
              src="{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '533x' }}"
              sizes="(min-width: {{ settings.page_width }}px) {{ settings.page_width | minus: 130 | divided_by: 4 }}px, (min-width: 990px) calc((100vw - 130px) / 4), (min-width: 750px) calc((100vw - 120px) / 3), calc((100vw - 35px) / 2)"
              alt="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.alt | escape }}"
              loading="lazy"
              class="motion-reduce"
              width="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.width }}"
              height="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.height }}"
            >

            {%- if product_card_product.media[1] != nil and show_secondary_image -%}
              <img
                srcset="{%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 165 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '165x' }} 165w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 360 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '360x' }} 360w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 533 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '533x' }} 533w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 720 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '720x' }} 720w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 940 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '940x' }} 940w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 1066 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '1066x' }} 1066w,{%- endif -%}
                  {{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: 'master' }} {{ product_card_product.media[1].width }}w"
                src="{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '533x' }}"
                sizes="(min-width: {{ settings.page_width }}px) {{ settings.page_width | minus: 130 | divided_by: 4 }}px, (min-width: 990px) calc((100vw - 130px) / 4), (min-width: 750px) calc((100vw - 120px) / 3), calc((100vw - 35px) / 2)"
                alt="{{ product_card_product.media[1].alt | escape }}"
                loading="lazy"
                class="motion-reduce"
              width="{{ product_card_product.media[1].width }}"
              height="{{ product_card_product.media[1].height }}"
              >
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- else -%}
        <div class="card__content">
          <h2 class="card__text h3">
            <a href="{{ product_card_product.url | default: '#' }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
              {{ product_card_product.title }}
            </a>
          </h2>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}

      <div class="card__badge">
        {%- if product_card_product.available == false -%}
          <span class="badge badge--bottom-left color-{{ settings.sold_out_badge_color_scheme }}">{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</span>
        {%- elsif product_card_product.compare_at_price > product_card_product.price and product_card_product.available -%}
          <span class="badge badge--bottom-left color-{{ settings.sale_badge_color_scheme }}">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
        {%- endif -%}
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% comment %} 
Code added by Colleen to create add to cart button 
{% endcomment %}



<form method="post" action="/cart/add">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product_card_product.first_available_variant.id }}" />
<input type="hidden" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="button" />

</form>

    {% endif %}          
    {% endfor %}
```

This is the section code:

```html
{% comment %}
also edited en.default.schema.json to add settings for 
featured-collection-gwp
{% endcomment %}

{{ 'component-card.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'component-price.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'component-product-grid.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'component-slider.css' | asset_url }}" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'template-collection.css' | asset_url }}" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">

<noscript>{{ 'component-slider.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}</noscript>
<noscript>{{ 'template-collection.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}</noscript>

{%- liquid
  assign products_to_display = section.settings.collection.all_products_count

  if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > section.settings.products_to_show
    assign products_to_display = section.settings.products_to_show
    assign more_in_collection = true
  endif
-%}
<div class="collection page-width{% if section.settings.swipe_on_mobile == true and section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 %} page-width-desktop{% endif %}">
  <div class="title-wrapper-with-link{% if section.settings.title == blank %} title-wrapper-with-link--no-heading{% endif %}{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 %} title-wrapper--self-padded-tablet-down{% endif %}>
    <h2 class="title{% if section.settings.title == blank %} title--no-heading{% endif %}">{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
 

    {%- if section.settings.show_view_all and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and more_in_collection -%}
      <a href="{{ section.settings.collection.url }}" class="link underlined-link large-up-hide">{{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all' | t }}</a>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>

  <slider-component class="slider-mobile-gutter">
   <ul id="gwp-section"
    class="grid grid--2-col product-grid{% if products_to_display == 4 or section.settings.collection == blank %} grid--2-col-tablet grid--4-col-desktop{% else %} grid--3-col-tablet{% endif %}{% if products_to_display > 5 %} grid--one-third-max grid--4-col-desktop grid--quarter-max{% endif %}{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 %} slider slider--tablet grid--peek{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_view_all == false or section.settings.collection.products.size < section.settings.products_to_show %} negative-margin{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_view_all and section.settings.collection.products.size > section.settings.products_to_show %} negative-margin--small{% endif %}" role="list">
      {%- for product in section.settings.collection.products limit: section.settings.products_to_show -%}
        <li class="grid__item{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 %} slider__slide{% endif %}" style="text-align:center;">
           {% render 'product-card-gwp',
            product_card_product: product,
            media_size: section.settings.image_ratio,
            show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
            add_image_padding: section.settings.add_image_padding,
            show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
            show_image_outline: section.settings.show_image_outline,
            show_rating: section.settings.show_rating
          %}
        </li>
      {%- else -%}
        {%- for i in (1..4) -%}
          <li class="grid__item">                               
            {% render 'product-card-placeholder' %}
          </li>
        {%- endfor -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      </ul>
    {%- if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 -%}
      <div class="slider-buttons no-js-hidden{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count < 4 %} medium-hide{% endif %}{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count < 3 %} small-hide{% endif %}">
        <button type="button" class="slider-button slider-button--prev" name="previous" aria-label="{{ 'accessibility.previous_slide' | t }}">{% render 'icon-caret' %}</button>
        <div class="slider-counter caption">
          <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.of' | t }}</span>
          <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display }}</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="slider-button slider-button--next" name="next" aria-label="{{ 'accessibility.next_slide' | t }}">{% render 'icon-caret' %}</button>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  </slider-component>

  {%- if section.settings.show_view_all and more_in_collection -%}
    <div class="center{% if section.settings.swipe_on_mobile %} small-hide medium-hide{% endif %}">
      <a href="{{ section.settings.collection.url }}"
        class="button"
        aria-label="{{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all_label' | t: collection_name: section.settings.collection.title }}"
      >
        {{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "spaced-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "default": "GWP Collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.title.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "collection",
      "id": "collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.collection.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "products_to_show",
      "min": 2,
      "max": 12,
      "step": 2,
      "default": 8,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.products_to_show.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_view_all.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "swipe_on_mobile",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.swipe_on_mobile.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.header.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_ratio",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "adapt",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.image_ratio.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "portrait",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.image_ratio.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "square",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.image_ratio.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "adapt",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.image_ratio.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_secondary_image",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_secondary_image.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "add_image_padding",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.add_image_padding.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_image_outline",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_image_outline.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_vendor.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_rating",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_rating.label",
      "info": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.settings.show_rating.info"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.featured-collection-gwp.presets.name"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: please show the for loop that you called for the sliders.

Comment: @CharlesC. The code above is the full code for the snippet, I will add the section code as well. Is that what you are looking for? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesC. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your suggested code and it didn't work, unfortunately.  I tried the code with your suggestion and also added the "for" statement that I had in my original code and neither worked. I end up with a blank section without any product. I suspect that the section code can't reference or "see" the variant level information, it might be collection/product level only. Does that make sense? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a suggestion from another forum to add some code to the theme.liquid above the `</body>` tag.

The solution works, but as the poster warned, is not the most elegant solution and could potentially cause other issues. However, posting here in case it could help someone else with a similar issue.

```html
<style>

</style>
<script>
function removeEmptySpaces(){

    var $items = document.querySelectorAll(`#gwp-section .grid__item`);

for (var each of $items){
    var $child = each.querySelector(`form`);

    if (!$child){
        each.remove();
    }
}
}
removeEmptySpaces()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for the code below;
before you `{% render 'product-card-gwp %}`, do a `if` condition;

```
{% if condition is met %}
<li class="grid__item{% if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > 2 and section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and section.settings.products_to_show > 2 %} slider__slide{% endif %}" style="text-align:center;">
       {% render 'product-card-gwp',
        product_card_product: product,
        media_size: section.settings.image_ratio,
        show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
        add_image_padding: section.settings.add_image_padding,
        show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
        show_image_outline: section.settings.show_image_outline,
        show_rating: section.settings.show_rating
      %}
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

also, use `variant.weight`, and `variant.weight_unit` instead, this will give you more flexibility since weight is a number and not a string.

```
{% assign theweight = variant.weight%}
{%- if theweight == 9 and variant.inventory_quantity != 0 -%}
```